# SQL Server Issue with Join and NULL Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get all entries from the table 'issued'  and display receipt information for that ISBN if it appears that day on the receipts daily table load. So I could have say 10 rows from issued, but 2 of them have receipt info that day so that data gets loaded in the proper columns from the receipts table. Otherwise just have them as NULLS. The joining keys would be ID and ISBN.

```
 SELECT dbo.issued.id
        ,dbo.issued.itemnum
        ,dbo.issued.issued_price
        ,dbo.issued.date_returned
        ,dbo.receipts_driver.Receipt_Num
        ,dbo.receipts_driver.Receipt_Date
        ,dbo.receipts_driver.Price
        ,dbo.receipts_driver.Title
    FROM dbo.receipts_driver
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.issued ON dbo.receipts_driver.ID = dbo.issued.id 
      aND dbo.receipts_driver.ISBN = dbo.issued.itemnum
```

That is what I have so far but it is not working correctly.

Any ideas on how I could set this up? This is driving me nuts.

Any information is appreciated.

UDPATE: Here is what I am trying to do:

```
+-----------+------------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+----------+----------+
| 1 COLUMN  |     2 COLUMN     |     3 COLUMN     |   4 COLUMN   |   5 COLUMN    |    6 COLUMN    |     7 COLUMN     | 8 COLUMN | 9 COLUMN |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+----------+----------+
| ID        | ISBN             | Date_Issued      | Issued Price | Date Returned | Receipt Number | Receipt Date     | Price    | Title    |
|           |                  |                  |              |               |                |                  |          |          |
| 235854589 | 9780133544015.00 | 1/21/16 12:00 AM | $250.00      | NULL          | NULL           | NULL             | NULL     | NULL     |
|           |                  |                  |              |               |                |                  |          |          |
| 235854589 | 9781118451564.00 | 1/21/16 12:00 AM | $39.00       | NULL          | NULL           | NULL             | NULL     | NULL     |
|           |                  |                  |              |               |                |                  |          |          |
| 235854589 | 9781269954280.00 | NULL             | $0.00        | NULL          | NULL           | NULL             | NULL     | NULL     |
|           |                  |                  |              |               |                |                  |          |          |
| 235854589 | 9781285746500.00 | NULL             | $0.00        | NULL          | NULL           | NULL             | NULL     | NULL     |
|           |                  |                  |              |               |                |                  |          |          |
| 235854589 | 9781285762890.00 | NULL             | $0.00        | NULL          | NULL           | NULL             | NULL     | NULL     |
|           |                  |                  |              |               |                |                  |          |          |
| 235854589 | 9781609806453.00 | 1/21/16 12:00 AM | $18.95       | NULL          | NULL           | NULL             | NULL     | NULL     |
|           |                  |                  |              |               |                |                  |          |          |
| 235854589 | 9781620970935.00 | 4/11/16 12:00 AM | $17.95       | NULL          | 56625          | 4/11/16 11:48 AM | 17.95    | Math 1   |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+----------+----------+
```

Everything from Receipt Number over would be from the receipts table, but just the one ISBN right now (9781620970935) is a match so you see the receipt number etc in the fields. The ones above would be Null.

Comment: `The joining keys would be ID and ISBN.` - Your query uses `Id` in both tables for the `JOIN`.  If the relation is as you state, you need to change your `JOIN` condition.

Comment: Sorry I have tried that. When I join by id and ISBN I only get an entry for the records in the receipts table. When I flip the join the other way I get all the records from issued. I only need the records from issued where the id is in the receipts table.

Comment: Can you please show sample data, your query results, and your expected result?

Comment: For instance I have one receipt in the receipt table, but 13 entries on the issued table. I want to display all 13 entries and show the recipt fields on just the ISBN match that is in the receipt table.

Comment: Please provide table structures, sample data, and expected output given that sample data so that people don't have to make guesses. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a good start. That said, your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` should probably be a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` or switch issued to the `FROM` clause.

Comment: `but it is not working correctly` - please define not working? What are you getting that you are not expecting. As @Siyual pointed out your join might be wrong, `receipts_driver.ID = dbo.issued.id`, unless the id column on both tables are meant to be joined on but most likely the id on one of those columns is not meant to be a FK.

Comment: @spacerobot If you want to show the 13 entries in the `issued` table and only show those from `receipt` if they exist, then you need to change your `LEFT JOIN` to a `RIGHT JOIN` (while also changing your `ON` clause to the appropriate fields)

Comment: or `FROM dbo.issued LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.receipts_driver`

Comment: I tried the right join and i get 2, 000 entries when max I should get 7. Here is my updated syntax.


    SELECT     dbo.issued.suid AS id, dbo.issued.itemnum, dbo.issued.issued_price, dbo.issued.date_returned, dbo.receipts_driver.Receipt_Num, dbo.receipts_driver.Receipt_Date, 
                      dbo.receipts_driver.Price, dbo.receipts_driver.Title, dbo.issued.date_issued
FROM         dbo.receipts_driver RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.issued ON dbo.receipts_driver.SUID = dbo.issued.suid AND dbo.receipts_driver.ISBN = dbo.issued.itemnum

Comment: @spacerobot You should [edit] your question and add that info instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: Updated original post. Thanks.

Comment: You really should post:
1. Tables definitions with key and fk
2. sample data
3. expected result on that data
because this looks like you talking about something else then you wrote e.g about what date you talking about?
Simple will be 
    SELECT FIELDS FROM ISSUED I LEFT JOIN receipts_driver R ON R.ID=I.ID AND I.SOME_DATE=R.SOME_DATE

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this forum. I wasn't sure the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. I think you've missed out date_issued in your original query;

```
SELECT i.id
    ,i.itemnum
    ,i.date_issued
    ,i.issued_price
    ,i.date_returned
    ,rd.Receipt_Num
    ,rd.Receipt_Date
    ,rd.Price
    ,rd.Title
FROM issued i
LEFT JOIN recepts_driver rd
ON i.suid = rd.suid
AND i.itemnum = rd.ISBN
```

Comment: Thanks. This query returned all 2928 rows from issued and did not match up with any of the results from the RD table. The RD fields were all null without any entries in them. Currently there is 1 record in the rd table, and 7 in the issued table. If you look up above at my example that is the answer I am trying to achieve. I also noticed I had typos for the id field name that I corrected.

Comment: If the row for 9781620970935 is a match in both tables then does it have a different suid in each table? that would be the only reason that the join wouldn't work. if it has a different suid then just take that out of the join and just join on ISBN

Comment: I just verified the id's are the same in both table. In rd there is 1 record under that id, in issued there are 7 records for that id.

Comment: What about the ISBN's, do they match? if so you must be missing something with the data. If the joining fields were the same then it would work. Try to verify that you don't have blank spaces in one of the tables or anything daft like that. I noticed that your isbn has decimals too, this isn't stored as varchar is it?

Comment: I'm still looking at this. I have verified the ISBN and itemnums are the same, without any spaces or anything. And the ID is the same on both sides without any spaces. If I do a right join I get all the correct information but just one record for the one receipt that is waiting. Doing the left join like you included above returns 2900 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I ended up figuring it out and getting it to work. Thanks for the help and suggestions everyone. Here is the final query:

```
SELECT     i.itemnum, i.date_issued, i.issued_price, i.date_returned, rd.Receipt_Num, rd.Receipt_Date, rd.Price, i.id
FROM         dbo.issued AS i 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Receipts AS rd ON i.id = rd.ID AND i.itemnum = rd.ISBN
WHERE (i.id IN
      (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM dbo.Receipts))
```